# Add/return multiple properties of a global object with one function in JS

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use a HTML form with two fields to: create a new property within an object (like a new country e.g. 'Mexico') and append a new sub-property (continent e.g. 'North America'). The variable is this...

```
var countries = {
    India: {
        country: 'India',
        type: 'Asian'
    };
```

... and the HTML form inputs arg1 and arg2 into the below function:

```
function dropDown(arg1, arg2){
  return [countries[arg1] = {country: arg1}, countries[arg1] = {type: arg2}];
};
```

This doesn't work. Only the last value (type) of country is appended to the var countries. Can anyone tell me why and what you would do to add multiple sub-properties to one object?

Answer (score 0):

You're writing over `countries[arg1]` in the second part of your return statement
you first set it to `{country: arg1}` and then set that same value to `{type: arg2}`

It should be:

```
function dropDown(arg1, arg2){
  return [countries[arg1].country = arg1, countries[arg1].type = arg2];
};
```

You don't actually need to return anything either - assuming countries is outside of the dropdown function and you do not need an array returned:

```
function dropDown(arg1, arg2){
  countries[arg1].country = arg1;
  countries[arg1].type = arg2;
};
```

Comment: thanks, but i can't seem to get either to work. i've tried a few different things but i still get the following error for both:
TypeError: Cannot set property 'country' of undefined